# Incorporating domain knowledge into the learning process

Tags: classification

Let us say you have a classification dataset, where some of the examples are labelled not only with the target, but also with *why* the set of inputs should result in the target value (i.e. a set of important features that a domain expert would use to classify the example - e.g. this person sneezed because of pollen levels, not because it's warm and sunny).

What are some ways to incorporate this additional data in the learning process, particularly if using gradient boosted tree-like algorithms?

One I can think of is to incorporate this into an evaluation (CV or test set) metric, e.g. how important those features actually end up being for classifying those examples.

But is there any work out there on incorporating such data into the learning process? It seems like it could be very useful on smaller datasets where such domain knowledge is available, and where predictors A and B may be correlated with the target (and B may even be better correlated with the target in the dataset), but from domain knowledge we know that it is A that influences the target.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try a Statistical Relational Learning (SRL) tool?
[PSL](http://psl.linqs.org/) or [Alchemy](http://alchemy.cs.washington.edu/) could help you model some of that domain knowledge by allowing you to encode that information as first-order logic rules.

Let's consider a simple example in which you are trying to predict if a person will smoke or not. Let's say that you have some domain knowledge that says if a person's best friend smokes, then he/she smokes. In PSL, that would transcribe into a rule such as:

```
bestFriends(person1, person2) && smokes(person2) >> smokes(person1)
```

The rule can be read such as - if person1 and person2 are best friends and person2 smokes, then it implies that person1 smokes. While this is a first-order logic rule and can fail for certain data points, PSL allows you to handle this by introducing probability and doesn't harsh-fail on a non-conforming data point.